# is there a way to send notificatins automatically with firebase to flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a flutter application and I want to send notification to user if someone follows the user.I am using firebase and FCM to send notifications but I can only send them by hand.is there a way to send notification to user automatically when someone follows the user or etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the **server side of Firebase Cloud Messaging**, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server):

> The server side of Firebase Cloud Messaging consists of two
> components:
>
> - The FCM backend provided by Google.
> - Your app server or other trusted server environment where your server logic runs, **such as Cloud Functions for Firebase** or other cloud
>   environments managed by Google.
>
> Your app server or trusted server environment sends message requests
> to the FCM backend, which then routes messages to client apps running
> on users' devices.

The easiest solution is most probably to use Cloud Functions, unless you have your own server at hand.

There is an example for Cloud Functions in the official samples list: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications. The message sending is triggered by a new "record" in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) but it is quite easy to adapt it to be triggered by [Firestore documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but firebase says that i need to pay for cloud functions but this is more of a learning project of mine.guess I will not add the feature.

Comment: Actually what you need is to activate the Blaze payed Plan but there are some very generous free tiers, see https://firebase.google.com/pricing. For Cloud Functions it means you have 125000 free invocations per month. It should be ok ;-) For the other services it is the same: if your project is dedicated to learning you should never pay any dollar, since you will always be under the free tiers limits.